# How to get multiple latitude & longitude from google

Tags: google-maps

I create the file upload with the address of multiple location and store into database,now I want the latitude & longitude information of each address, I create the script using the curl which get the latitude & longitude information from google. But I have data size 2000 records so script get crash after 50 records, there any why using the cron job anything that help me out.

Answer (score 0):

your not allowed to do that according to the end user license agreement, the lat long data can only be used by a google map and hence not just for storing in a database.

I know that doesn't address your technical problem, but you need to look at API/licence that lets you do that.

Comment: hi,Thanks but google allow upto 2500 records so we can do it.But  thing is that one by one,any other way then please tell me  have dream day

Comment: I know you can do it technically but that doesn't mean that the license allows you, you need each record needs to be associated with a map that is displayed. I am guessing you are not displaying all 2500 maps at a time on a screen and showing it to the user?